# Light SpriteFont colors in MonoGame/XNA are low quality

Tags: c#, fonts, xna, monogame, spritefont

I am creating a game about internet safety but when using SpriteFont the light colours such as white or light blue come up really grainy and low quality. Black on the other hand is really clear. I was wondering if there is a way to fix this?

[Image with black colored SpriteFont](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niAQ9.png)

[Image with white colored SpriteFont](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Lc1g.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried increasing the size of the font to the double and set the scale to half?

You can do this by open your spritfont file with visual studio and edit the value inside the 'size' tag. Then set the scale when you call on DrawString:

```
float scale = 0.5f;
spriteBatch.DrawString(myFont, "Hello World", fontPosition, Color.White, 0f, 
    fontOrigin, scale, SpriteEffects.None, 0.5f);
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked really well! Just meant more adjusting with the centring but thanks all the same!